# Is there way to make array of strings from fields in array of object?

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregate

I using following query to get my result:

```
db.getCollection('simbanks').aggregate(
[{$match:{"groupId":ObjectId("x"), "organizationId": ObjectId("y")}},
{$lookup:{from:"sims",localField:"parentSn", foreignField:"parentSn",as:"sims"}},
])
```

With lookup for sims I get array of object. Is it possible to make array of strings from one field from those documents?

For example lookup returns 3 documents and each of them have field `name` how I would make array of string of all those `names`?

I have tried using `objectToArray` and etc so far with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was easy:

```
{
    $addFields:{
        "simsIMSIs": "$sims.imsi"
    }
}
```

Using $addFields I easily got my array of strings.